# Woocommerce Product Attributes conditional display

Tags: select, attributes, woocommerce, product, visible

Running woocommerce on my site. I'm using product variation where I have added 5 drop downs( Select) which when selected with values results in a price.
I want when value in the first drop down is selected only then the next drop down becomes visible. Until then only the first is visible. When the second is selected, third becomes visible. How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with conditional logic in Gravity Forms. You'll need to purchase Gravity Forms and the Woocommerce Gravity Forms product addon.

After you have both plugins, you create a new form. When you add your options you can select the advanced options tab and click conditional logic. Then you can set the field to show or hide depending on what is selected by the user. Here is brief description http://www.gravityforms.com/features/conditional-logic/
Then you add the form to your product in the edit product section.

You'll need these:

http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/

http://www.gravityforms.com/

These two plugins also make it way easier to add multiple and complex variations of a product without having to do all the calculations yourself.

Hope this helps.